# Equivalent Optimization Problems (another)

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Consider the following two optimization problems

$$\underset{x}{\text{min}} f(x) \quad \text{s.t.}\quad Ax=b$$

$$\underset{x}{\text{min}}\left[ f(x) + \mathbb{\lambda}^T(Ax-b)\right]$$

with $f(x)$ any continuous differentiable function of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a vector of weights that should be chosen to minimize the argument. Is it correct to say these two problems are equivalent because they both have the same Lagrangian?

$$L(x) = f(x) + \lambda^T(Ax-b)$$

UPDATE: I would like to revise the question, after receiving a few comments, to refer to these optimization problems instead

$$\underset{x}{\text{min}} f(x) \quad \text{s.t.}\quad Ax=b$$

$$\underset{x}{\text{min}}\left[ f(x) + ||Ax-b||_2\right]$$

where there exists $x$ such that $Ax=b$.

Comment: No, you need to have minimum at $0$ (vector) for $Ax-b$ or there is no chance that they are equivalent. Norms are a way to do that. Maybe $+\lambda\|Ax-b\|$

Comment: I don't know what you mean. They still seem the same to me. Could you expand a little on your point about needing a minimum at $0$?

Comment: $Ax-b$ can become negative when differing from $Ax=b$ then you would think you get an even better value for your objective function when in reality the point is not even allowed. A norm can never become negative so if we use one then we are sure that differing from $Ax=b$ will cause a positive cost which we want to avoid when minimizing.

Comment: Thank you, I see your point now. If I changed the second problems form to what you suggest using a norm, would they be equivalent? Maybe I should add that $Ax=b$ is well posed, so that an $x$ exists that satisfies this equality.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, they are NOT equivalent. Every optimal solution of the first problem ($x^*$) would satisfy $Ax^* = b$ and thus, would yield the same objective function value ($f(x^*)$) for both problems, but this may not be optimal for the second problem. Going the other way round, every optimal solution for the second problem may not always be an optimal solution for the first problem. Also note that the second problem has the $\lambda$s included in its decision variables. This is not the case for the first problem.

This argument is based on the assumption that two optimization problems are equivalent if their optimal value(s) and optimal solution(s) are the same. Things may be different under different equivalency criteria.

For example: $\min_x x^2$ s.t. $x = 2$ is minimum at $x=2$ and has minimum value $4$. However $\min_{x,\lambda} x^2 + \lambda(x-2)$ has minimum value tending to negative infinity when $x = -\lambda/2$ and $\lambda$ tends to positive infinity.